# How do I detect a line collison in LIBGDX?

Tags: collision-detection, libgdx

I am drawing a continuous line using Pixmap. I want to check for a collision / intersection of my line with the already drawn line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can check if any Intersection exist between your two lines as below.

**Problem:** Given **n** line segments; Report all(as **k** in algorithms) Intersections.

You can implement any of these two algorithm in your desire language and use them. they take your line segments as input and return if any intersection ( Collision in your case) exists.

Note: **Time/Space complexity of these algorithms for collision detection break with k=1**. because as you see first intersection, you can stop algorithm and report collision.

---

**Solution 1:** [Sweep Algorithm (Bentley, Ottmann '79)](http://geomalgorithms.com/a09-_intersect-3.html)

**Time Complexity: O(n*lg(n)+k)**

**Space Complexity: O(n+k)**

**Pseudo Code:**

```
ReportIntersections()
{

    Initialize event queue EQ = all segment endpoints;
    Sort EQ by increasing x and y;
    Initialize sweep line SL to be empty;
    Initialize output intersection list IL to be empty;

    While (EQ is nonempty) {
        Let E = the next event from EQ;
        If (E is a left endpoint) {
            Let segE = E's segment;
            Add segE to SL;
            Let segA = the segment Above segE in SL;
            Let segB = the segment Below segE in SL;
            If (I = Intersect( segE with segA) exists)
                Insert I into EQ;
            If (I = Intersect( segE with segB) exists)
                Insert I into EQ;
        }
        Else If (E is a right endpoint) {
            Let segE = E's segment;
            Let segA = the segment Above segE in SL;
            Let segB = the segment Below segE in SL;
            Delete segE from SL;
            If (I = Intersect( segA with segB) exists)
                If (I is not in EQ already)
                    Insert I into EQ;
        }
        Else {  // E is an intersection event
            Add E’s intersect point to the output list IL;
            Let segE1 above segE2 be E's intersecting segments in SL;
            Swap their positions so that segE2 is now above segE1;
            Let segA = the segment above segE2 in SL;
            Let segB = the segment below segE1 in SL;
            If (I = Intersect(segE2 with segA) exists)
                If (I is not in EQ already)
                    Insert I into EQ;
            If (I = Intersect(segE1 with segB) exists)
                If (I is not in EQ already)
                    Insert I into EQ;
        }
        remove E from EQ;
    }
    return IL;
}
```

---

**Solution 2:** Divide & Conquer Algorithm (Balaban '95)

**Complexity: O(n*lg(n)+k)**

**Space Complexity: O(n)**