# Libgdx--how to store every single point drawn using touchdragged?

Tags: collision-detection, libgdx, touch

Basically i am trying to detect line collision. The problem is when intersection occurs quickly(touch dragged is done quickly like fling), the collision is not detected. It seems as if 'touch dragged' doesn't store all points.

Comment: This might be helpful -- http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/89893/57316

Comment: Thank you. I have checked that but it seems very complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Touch screen record discrete points with a non-constant rate depending on how busy the CPU is and how reliable the hardware readings are.

You need to "connect" those points as lines (old point from last game loop to new point) when checking for collisions and calculate line-line or line-circle intersection (or other type of line-object intersection).

You can also sub-divide the line and test multiple points on the line for collision to keep things simple.